# Como remover um texto com acentos no php?

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte situação, o texto abaixo ele tem as seguintes palavras `ATENÇÃO:` e `será` que por sua vez elas são acentuadas, elas devem ser removidas do texto mas devido os acentos não consigo remover.

```
$string = "ATENÇÃO: O produto será revisado e constatado o defeito será";

$remover = array ("ATENÇÃO:","será");

echo $texto = str_replace("$remover","",$string);
```

Resultado esperado.

> O produto revisado e constatado o defeito

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua lógica funciona perfeitamente com acentos, o problema é que você está transformando o *array* com elementos para remover em uma *string*.

Veja o seguinte, só mudei a declaração de *array* para *short sintax* e removi as aspas extras:

```
<?php

$string = "ATENÇÃO: O produto será revisado e constatado o defeito será";

$remover = ["ATENÇÃO:","será"];

echo $texto = str_replace($remover, "", $string);
```

Veja funcionando [aqui](https://3v4l.org/q14WP).

PS.: Atenção com as mensagens de erro, ao [rodar sua função original](https://3v4l.org/fLpSU) estava retornando o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in /in/fLpSU on line 7

Answer (score 2):

Tire as aspas duplas da variável `$remover`.

```
echo $texto = str_replace($remover,"",$string);`
```

Veja funcionado no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/hxdi3q)

Comment: Mesmo tirando as aspas duplas não tenho o resultado esperado.

Comment: Pode colocar o código todo que está testando, o que estão dentro das tags php ? Eu testei aqui e está funcionando, só estou confirmando a relação com o link que coloquei na minha resposta...

Comment: Meu problema esta com a resposta que o banco de dados dá, pois visualmente ele aparece com o acento, mas internamente ele aparece caracteres especiais, quando se faz o teste isolado como eu coloquei no exemplo ele da certo, como sua resposta deu certo, porem quando eu uso $row['texto'] o resultado é outro.

Comment: Então, como eu disse coloca o código real que está usando...

Comment: Consegui resolver com estas funções utf8_encode e utf8_decode